# How to dublicate WC Product title to shortdescription field?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Need dublicate (copy) WC Product title to short description field. Please help with a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below action in your `functions.php` in Current theme for duplicate Product title in Short description field.

```
<?php
add_action( 'publish_product', function ( $post_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->update(
        'wp_posts',
        array(
            'post_excerpt' => get_the_title( $post_id ),
        ),
        array( 'ID' => $post_id )
    );
}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I gotted 504 Gateway Time-out

nginx-reuseport/1.11.10

Comment: How I can see - the function is executed several times, after which the process is down

Comment: Updated! please get new code and try again.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget select useful answer :)